# laravel How to check record in table connect to users table

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new in laravel and maybe its strange question, I don't want any user to redirect to specific page if two conditions are not valid:

1st - user already logged in

2nd - in customer table which connect to user table in(customer_id=user_id) check if package for this user == 1

So I have 2 tables:

one for users

```
user_id
user_email
user_password
```

and customer table

```
customer_id
package number
```

If user logged in and if customer_id=current logged user id and package ==1, redirect. Hope any body can help me.

I know how to check for the table users but how to check for the table customers for the same customer id

```
     @if(auth()->user()->user_id== 0)
```

Comment: Do you have a relation between customer and user?

Comment: Make this type of condition in controller and pass one variable

Comment: yes I have relationship

Comment: You can set proposed code from answers into custom middleware and use combo of `['auth', 'customMiddleware']` for chosen route(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use this.

In your User Model

```
class User extends Model
{
    //bunch of codes

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Customers', 'customer_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

then in your condition

```
if(Auth::attempt(array('user_email' => $email, 'user_password' => $pass), true)
    && Auth::user()->customer->package_number == 1){
    //do some magic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
//use Auth Facade...


if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->customer->package_number == 1) {
    //redirect to destination
}else{
    //redirect to error page
}
```